# Configuring a Yii2 Application As A Dependency

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I'm an experienced Yii2 developer, but I've never configured Yii2 as a dependency for another project before.

I'm implementing a custom Yii2 application as a backend/scaffold behind a legacy application which I'm modifying.  As such, I have composer set up to load my Yii2 project as a dependency, and I have the autoloader configured to bring my Yii2 models, etc into the legacy application.  This is all working really well.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot actually interact with the Yii application, for example to implement a backend REST API, or to use Gii, or to use the debugger, because Yii is buried in the vendors folder and has no ability to intercept the incoming routes (nor do I want it to, except for a few api calls, gii, etc).

Right now I have a second copy of the Yii application hosted alongside in order to overcome this problem, but it's cumbersome.

What is the correct way to use Yii2 as a composer dependency but still interact with it directly when you want to?

Comment: I might even be able to get by with just the Models being shared in a better way -- is there a way to package up the models as their own composer dependency, so I can keep them up to date in both applications?

Comment: Have you gone through this [link](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/using-yii-in-third-party-apps.md) ? not sure if it solves all of your problems

Comment: What's the **exact** problem? What do you mean by "cannot actually interact"? Is there any error message given?